# ListBoxItem MouseUp Event doesnt fire

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I created a ListBox with ListBoxItems and add an MouseDown event handler to each of the ListBoxItems. The ListBoxItems are shown, but when I click on a ListBoxItem, the Event doesn't get fired.

How i set the MouseUp:

```
TrackedProcessList.ItemsSource = null;
TrackedProcessList.ItemsSource = this.tracks;

/*... some other code that doesn't matter ... */

ListBoxItem[] items = new ListBoxItem[TrackedProcessList.Items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < TrackedProcessList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Object obj = TrackedProcessList.Items.GetItemAt(i);
    //TrackedProcessList.UpdateLayout();
    ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)(TrackedProcessList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
    if (item != null) 
    {
        item.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListBoxItem_MouseUp_PostQuestion);
        items[i] = item;
    }
}
```

The Method which should be called (but it isn't):

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseUp_PostQuestion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ListBoxItem_MouseUp_fired");
}
```

My XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="TrackedProcessList" Height="145" Width="605" ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="1,0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock  MouseDown="ListBoxItem_MouseUp_PostQuestion" Text="{Binding Path=programName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Do you have any ideas where the failure could be? There is no error. The Event just seems to be not bound to the ListBoxItem.

Comment: just as typo mark `item.MouseDown` should be `item.MouseUp`

Comment: Your right. i canged it ;-)

Comment: Can´t you use the `SelectionChanged`-Event of the ListBox?

Comment: @Laokoon so dies it work now :o)

Comment: @WiiMaxx: no it doesn't work that way. But thanks :-)

Comment: @Jehof: SelectionChanged gives me the sourceItem not the ListBoxItem which i need.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't bubble up to your from your SourecItem to your ListBoxItem depending on the type of your SourceItem?

Comment: Use the PreviewMouseDown event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `ListBoxItem` already handles both left and right click which means your event handler will not be triggered according to WPF routed event rules. Your either have to assign `PreviewMouseDown` event or add event handler for handled events:

```
lbi.AddHandler(ListBoxItem.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(MouseEvent), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnListBox_Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled
}

void OnListBox_Mouse_Up(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   "Do Something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ContainedControl property and set your events :)

```
kryptonListBox1.ContainedControl.MouseDown += kryptonListBox1_MouseDown_1;
```